# EFI loads GRUB which loads OS kernel, what happens inside physical memory?

Tags: boot, kernel, bootloader

In a normal boot process:

1. ROM seeks and loads a program in EFI partition into RAM.
2. This EFI program seeks and loads GRUB program (normally in `/boot/grub`) into RAM.
3. This GRUB program finally loads the OS kernels (`initrd`, `vmlinux/z`) into RAM.

(A side note, there was no `/boot/efi` mount point at boot)

In all cases, the OS kernel always possesses kernel space of **virtual memory** which every *user process* sees as the beginning part of its virtual memory.

My question is: **Where did ROM program, EFI program and GRUB program go after finishing their loading task?**

*More technically*, is it possible for a program `A` to **load** another program `B` then **pass** the **control** of the whole system to `B` then `A` *vanishes to the air*?